# Common utility methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, software-design

In our organisation, we are going to start the new development project in .net core API /Angular / SQL . We thought of adding utilities like logging, file operations , mail functions , common data table functions , list extension methods. Can someone help what else we can do more ?

Comment: It depends on your project requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important principles in software development is YAGNI (you ain't gonna need it).

Don't implement stuff you might eventually need at some point in the future. We all suck at predicting the future. And we suck at it big time, with no exception. So if you aren't really forced to do it, just don't.

And remember that all code needs to be tested and maintained. Therefore less code is better. You can always add stuff later.